# Select matrix column (resp. row) as Nx1 (resp. 1xD) matrix, as opposed to vector

Tags: r

Let `X` be an `N` by `D` matrix. Selecting a submatrix of size `n` by `d` returns a matrix of those dimensions **unless** at least one of `n` and `d` equals 1, in which case we get a vector instead. Interestingly, R still returns a matrix of the correct dimensions even if one of `n` and `d` are 0, and the other **not** 1.

Now, if we are certain that `n!=1`, then executing `cbind(X[row.subset,col.subset])` will return a matrix of the correct dimensions regardless of whether `d==1` or not (here `n=length(row.subset)` and `d=length(col.subset)`). If we are certain that `d!=1`, then we can use `rbind(...)`. But if both `n` and `d` can be 1, neither approach will work since we could accidentally turn a row into a column or vice versa.

As far as I can tell, one way to always get a matrix of the right dimensions is to call `matrix(X[row.subset,col.subset],nrow=n,ncol=d)`. However, it doesn't feel like that should be the right way to go about it, plus I'm not confident that there is no performance penalty. Is there a more "native" solution?

Here's a working example:

```
N <- 6
D <- 3
X <- matrix(rnorm(N*D),ncol=D)

dim(X[1:2,1:2]) #returns 2 2
dim(X[1:2,1]) #returns NULL, this is a vector

dim(cbind(X[1:2,1])) #returns 2 1
dim(cbind(X[1,1:2])) #returns 2 1, but we'd like it to be 1 2

dim(rbind(X[1,1:2])) #returns 1 2
dim(rbind(X[1:2,1])) #returns 1 2, but we'd like it to be 2 1

row.subset <- 1:4
col.subset <- 2
#I _think_ this is always correct, but it's verbose:
matrix(X[row.subset,col.subset],nrow=length(row.subset),ncol=length(col.subset))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a quick comment: there's very little performance penalty to making a vector into a matrix -- you're just setting dimension attributes

Comment: FYI:  there is a `drop` argument to `[`.   If you set that to `FALSE` then you will get a matrix for all `n`

Comment: @DWin done, I think (I just need to mark the answer Ista's answer as accepted, right?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to simplify matrix subsets to vectors just tell `[` not to drop dimensions:

```
> dim(X[1:2,1, drop=FALSE])
[1] 2 1
> dim(X[1,1:2, drop=FALSE])
[1] 1 2
```

See `?"["` for details.